# Android: Tiled game and interaction between player and other objects

Tags: android

I'm learning to use a [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) map on android. I've got a TMX file and I loaded the map successfully, but I don't know how to control interaction between the player and other objects in my game. All objects on the map right now are lifeless. For example in Super Mario Bros., when Mario headbutts a block, the block needs to move or break. I plan to code a class for block, but then my map creation would become difficult; I couldn't "draw" my maps visually.

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished this by using the layers concept in the TMX file. Something like [Tiled](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://mapeditor.org/&ei=_5lOT_n8CIaV0QHgsKzgAg&usg=AFQjCNGFOeUE3IDtfigGs1DO8zSMXejTtg&sig2=hrnSz7XKKj4mJwdDCiRlUA) allows you to craft your maps in this manner. When you are reading in the TMX file you can look for any objects with a certain property like **block** and add those into your game yourself. Then you are free to interact with the object however you want.

To get an idea you can check out my implementation at https://github.com/methodin/Particly/blob/master/src/com/sordid/particly/ParticlyActivity.java
(search for TMX)

This uses Andengine's TMX parser but the concept should be the same:

1. Load the TMX file
2. Loop through the layers and objects
3. Check a property on the object like name=block and add the blocks into the game using the coordinates from the TMX file

You could still potentially do this using the TMX tiles itself but it's a little bit more restricted and you'd have to work within the bounds of the TMX parser/display library you are using or build it yourself.

Comment: thank you very much, I will try to read that code. It's so clear for me. Thanks

Comment: I've read that code, so i think i can do same things. I mean i want to control a block, move it or break it. i emphasize that a block that be  loaded from map. Please help me.